# Input string was not in correct formate while inserting data to postgresql through entityframework in .net core using dynamic query

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am getting error while inserting data to pgsql with  .net core entity framework
error is **Input string was not in correct format**
this is my query executing

`INSERT INTO public."MedQuantityVerification"("Id","MedId","ActivityBy","ActivityOn","Quantity","ActivityType","SupposedOn","Note") Values(7773866,248953,8887,'7/14/2018 10:43:43 PM','42.5 qty',5,NULL,'I counted forty two {point} five.')`

anyhow when I run that query directly to postgresql browser it works fine
looks like issue on c# side it is but not know what?
***also issue is with {point}***

this is how I executing the dynamic query

***db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(query);***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the curly brackets:

{point} should be {{point}}

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteSqlRaw` utilizes curly braces to parameterize the raw query so if your query naturally includes them like OP's does the function is going to try and parse them. Doubling up the braces like in Koen Schepens' answer acts as an escape sequence and tells the function not to parse it as a parameter.

The [documentation for the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-6.0) uses the following example as to the purpose of why it does what it does:

```
var userSuppliedSearchTerm = ".NET";
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("UPDATE Blogs SET Rank = 50 WHERE Name = {0}", userSuppliedSearchTerm);
```

Note that you'll want to use this to your advantage any time you're accepting user-input and passing it to `ExecuteSqlRaw`. If the curly brace is in a parameter instead of the main string it doesn't need to be escaped.